# Black screen shown after camera intent

Tags: java, android, google-glass

I modified the StopWatch demo Glass app to start the Camera activity via request when the side is tapped. The intent code is copied from Google's documentation.

When I tap, the onPause callback for my app is fired, but the screen transitions to black instead of a camera preview. Tapping again does nothing—onResume is not called. Swiping down does transition me back to the StopWatch activity, however.

Does this look like a bug with the camera intent on Glass, or is it something on my end?

**StopWatch Activity**

```
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100; // 1337 also doesn't work

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  switch (keyCode) {
  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20130812_105617.jpg

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    return true;
  default:
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.google.glass.samples.stopwatch"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.glass.samples.stopwatch.StopWatchActivity"
        android:label="StopWatch" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat**

```
470      862-862/com.google.glass.samples.stopwatch D/GOOGLE1: Touched side
470      862-862/com.google.glass.samples.stopwatch D/GOOGLE1: Pause
533      862-862/com.google.glass.samples.stopwatch D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 1)
611      190-216/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.google.glass.camera/.CameraApiActivity: +142ms
619      862-862/com.google.glass.samples.stopwatch D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
142      190-213/? I/power: *** set_screen_state 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your code is correct. Please file a bug report on our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) .

As an alternative, you may want to try using the [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) class directly to capture photos.

Comment: You can star the issue to follow it here: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=173